# Can we use python 3.6 with cassandra 3.11 to run CQL commands?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I see that in cassandra prerequisite (https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites) it has been mentioned that we will be able to use python 3.6+ version for using CQL.

I have currently installed python 2.7 as per the initial requirement, now as 2.7 has been deprecated I want to move to Python 3.6. If i move to python 3.6 will i still be able to run all CQLSH commands smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10190, Python 3 support is available is only in Cassandra 4 that isn’t released yet... So you need to use Python 2.7

Comment: okey but i installed cassandra in my mac which has python 3.6, i was able to run CQL commands fine. Am i missing something here?

Comment: As I remember, it won't fail for some commands, only for specific ones.  As I see from the commit log, support for Python 3 was added in the middle of February, and only into master branch that is 4.0: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/commit/bf9a1d487b9ba469e8d740cf7d1cd419535a7e79#diff-063288b62e3bbc873aaa9b39b46b1438a6ee73d654f2445eff0dafb13cd842e6, and this isn't backported to the 3.11

Comment: Alex is correct -- Python 3.6+ isn't tested or supported pre-C* 4.0. Cheers!